# How to convert $ character with Code39 in CrystalReports?

Tags: crystal-reports, code39

I need to display a numeric value (document number) as barcode. I use Code39 to convert.
It is important to concatenate %-character as first, and $-character as last character to my number.

Here is my code:

`Code39Full ("%" & ToText({Command.DocNum}, 0, '') & "$")`

That should show up:

> %217006169$

but it appears this:

> %217006169/D

Any suggestion?

Comment: Where are you getting your `Code39Full()` function?  Is this a UDL (User Defined Library, usually referencing a DLL file).  When I encode barcodes in Crystal Reports, I have two UDLs for Code 39 barcodes, one is Azalea (u25azalea.dll) and Bar (u2lbar.dll) and I am unable to recreate the results you are describing in your output.  I suspect your UDL function may be the culprit, and may not be encoding all of the special characters correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the easyest solution for my problem.

Steps for the right barcode:

1. Creating a new formula for the barcode with the following text:
2. `"%" & CStr({Command.DocNum}, 0, '') & "$"`
3. Drag and drop the formula into the document
4. Right click on the formula
5. Choose the "Change - Barcode..." option, than
6. Choose "Code39" from the list
7. Click "OK" :)

Now it works perfectly!

With this CrystalReports built-in tool no needid choosing the font type, or inserting any barcode function into the formula.